# Ruby character encoding when using Base64.encode

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, base64

Looking at the source of Ruby's Base64.encode I cannot determine what character encoding a string is converted to, if at all, before encoding that data in Base64. A Utf-8 string encoded in Base64 is going to be a lot different than a Utf-16 string encoded in Base64. Does Ruby make any promises regarding this operation?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An example to encode and decode an utf-8 string in base64:

```
text = "intérnalionálização"
 => "intérnalionálização"
text.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
encoded = Base64.encode64(text)
 => "aW50w6lybmFsaW9uw6FsaXphw6fDo28=\n"
encoded.encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
decoded = Base64.decode64(encode)
 => "int\xC3\xA9rnalion\xC3\xA1liza\xC3\xA7\xC3\xA3o"
decoded.encoding
 => #<Encoding:US-ASCII>
decoded = decoded.force_encoding('UTF-8')
 => "intérnalionálização"
decoded.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Interesting. The string returned from decode64 is US-ASCII and contains a bunch of escaped characters. I suppose that's a pretty good indicator that it converts it to US-ASCII before base64 encoding it as well.

Comment: To understand: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Base64.html and http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack

Comment: If you want to try out Victor's code in an irb session, then make sure you do `require 'base64'` first.

Comment: You've just saved my night! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-encode64) has this to say:

> **encode64(bin)**
>   Returns the Base64-encoded version of bin. This method complies with RFC 2045.

Section 6.8 of [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) says:

> **6.8.  Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding**
>
> The Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding is designed to represent arbitrary sequences of octets in a form that need not be humanly readable. [...]
>
> A 65-character subset of US-ASCII is used, enabling 6 bits to be represented per printable character. (The extra 65th character, "=", is used to signify a special processing function.)

So Base64 encodes *bytes* into ASCII. If those bytes actually represent a UTF-8 encoded string then the UTF-8 string will be broken down into individual bytes and those bytes will be converted to Base64; for example, if you have a UTF-8 string `'µ'` then you'll end up encoding the bytes `0xc2` and `0xb5` (in that order) to the Base64 representation `"wrU=\n"`. If you start out with a binary string `"\xc2\xb5"` (which just happens to match the UTF-8 version of `'µ'`) then you'll get the same `"wrU=\n"` output.

When you decode `"wrU=\n"`, you'll get the bytes `"\xc2\xb5"` and you'll have to know that those bytes are supposed to be UTF-8 encoded text rather than some arbitrary blob of bits. This is why you have separate content type and character set meta data attached to the Base64.

Similarly, if you have a UTF-16 string then it will be broken into bytes and those bytes will be encoded just like any other byte string. Of course this case is a little more complicated due to byte order issues but that's why we have content type and character set headers and BOMs.

The main point is that Base64 works with *bytes*, not characters. What format (UTF-8 text, UTF-16 text, a PNG image, ...) is someone else's problem. Base64 just converts a byte stream to a subset of US ASCII and then back to bytes; the format of those bytes must be specified separately.

---

I did some poking around in the source and the results might be of interest even if they're not completely relevant. The [`encode64` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/lib/base64.rb#L37) is simply this:

```
def encode64(bin)
  [bin].pack("m")
end
```

Then if you look through [`Array#pack`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/pack.c#L368):

```
static VALUE
pack_pack(VALUE ary, VALUE fmt)
{
    /*...*/
    int enc_info = 1;       /* 0 - BINARY, 1 - US-ASCII, 2 - UTF-8 */
```

and keep an eye on `enc_info`, you'll see that a `'m'` format will leave `enc_info` alone so the packed string will come out as US-ASCII and so `encode64` will produce US ASCII output as expected.

Comment: This agrees with my suspicions in the comments of Victor's answer. Thanks for confirming.